# Amazon AWS and Varnish - trouble accessing varnishncsa command

Tags: amazon-web-services, varnish

Having issues with adding items to varnish logging.

I am able to start and stop varnishncsa, and things look clear on varnish status, however, when attempting to add logging for PURGE, using the varnishncsa command, I'm getting command not found errors.

`sudo systemctl status rh-varnish6-varnishncsa
● rh-varnish6-varnishncsa.service - Varnish Cache HTTP accelerator NCSA logging daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/../../../../rh-varnish6-varnishncsa.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-08-05 13:42:14 EDT; 3h 1min ago
 Main PID: 28620 (varnishncsa)
   CGroup: /...../rh-varnish6-varnishncsa.service
           └─28620 /../../../../../../varnishncsa -a -w /.../op...
Aug 05 13:42:14 ip-..-...-..-...ec2.internal systemd[1]: Starting Varnish Cac...
Aug 05 13:42:14 ip-..-...-..-...ec2.internal systemd[1]: Started Varnish Cach...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.`


`sudo rh-varnish6-varnishncsa -g request -q 'ReqMethod eq "PURGE"'
sudo: rh-varnish6-varnishncsa: command not found`

Running the same command as sudo varnishncsa -g request -q 'ReqMethod eq "PURGE"' produces the same result.

Has anyone come across this issue before? I'm trying to configure my logs to look into some caching issues.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure on how you configured Varnish on AWS, but `rh-varnish6-varnishncsa` is probably not the command you're looking for.

Based on your output, there's a *systemd* service called `rh-varnish6-varnishncsa.service`, which starts up a `varnishncsa` service that gets logged to a specific location.

### varnishlog *vs* varnishncsa

`varnishncsa` is a useful binary to gather stats on what happens on a running Varnish system. Because it is in *NCSA* format, logprocessers can easily get metrics out of them.

Because your origin server will get a lot less hits, `varnishncsa` could be the surrogate for those kinds of logs.

However, `varnishncsa` is not really the right tool when you want to perform debugging. The `varnishlog` binary is a far superior tool for that.

If you want to know what's going on with specific calls, and you want to debug `PURGE` calls, you can use the same [vsl-query syntax](http://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/vsl-query.html) you're currently using in your `varnishncsa` command.

### Debugging with varnishlog

In your case, the following command would make sense to debug:

```
varnishlog -g request -q 'ReqMethod eq "PURGE"'
```

The output you'll get will be a lot more verbose and actionable.

A couple of years ago I wrote a really extensive blog post on how to leverage `varnishlog`. You can read it [here](https://feryn.eu/blog/varnishlog-measure-varnish-cache-performance/). It contains information on how to use the different parameters of the `varnishlog` binary, but also about the *vsl-query* syntax.

### Still use varnishncsa

`varnishncsa` can still play a role in your setup. If you found what you're looking for using `varnishlog`, you might want to look out for similar anomalies in the future.

Because of the verbosity of `varnishlog`, it's tough to persist these kinds of logs on disk. You could set up a different *systemd* service that logs these specific cases in a separate log file.

As far as your `rh-varnish6-varnishncsa` goes: please use that one as an `access_log` replacement you usually get when running an *Apache* or *Nginx* server.

### An extra piece of advice regarding AWS

If you're running Varnish on AWS, it can make a lot of sense to run EC2 instances from the official Varnish Software images.

There are images for [Varnish Cache 6](http://varnish-cache.org/). But there are also images for [Varnish Enterprise 6](https://www.varnish-software.com/solutions/varnish-enterprise/), which comes with a lot of extra features.

Have a look at the docs page for Varnish Enterprise: https://docs.varnish-software.com/.

Here's our AWS marketplace profile page, which contains the various *EC2 images* we offer: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=263c0208-6a3a-435d-8728-fa2514202fd0